# Replace all references to a object in a shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Is it possible to replace the object where multiple instances of a shared_ptr refer to?
Maybe I am not really clear, so I'll give an example:

```
shared_ptr<Base> a = new Derived1();
auto b = a;
auto c = b;

// This function replaces the object where a, b, and c point to.
magic(a, new Derived2());
```

I have looked into the member functions of shared_ptr (reset and swap) with no luck.

Comment: Thanks, I editted my question so it becomes more clear that I want it to work which inheritence. However your second suggestion would probably be exactly what I want, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an additional layer of indirection:

```
shared_ptr<unique_ptr<Base>> a = unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived1());
auto b = a;
auto c = b;

// This modifies the `unique_ptr` that `a` `b` and `c` point to
// to point to a new Derived2.
*a = unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived2());
```

Comment: @Tim: `shared_from_this` will not work, as the `shared_ptr` is holding a `unique_ptr`, rather than a `DerivedX` object.

Comment: If I would create a custom unique pointer it would be possible right?

Comment: would doing *c= unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived2()) also work? Then the A and B would have new object?

Comment: @Dariusz: Yes, a, b and c all have the same behaviour in that regard.