# How to "reassign" a shared_ptr<base> to a new derived object

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, shared-ptr

I'm writing an interpretive language using C++. Now the problem is I want to implement features like reassignment:

```
VAR a = [1,"2",[3,4]]
VAR a[0] = 100
```

In my language, a List is a `vector` of `shared_ptr<Data>`, so that you can store different types of data in one list. If someone wants to change an element, I can get the `shared_ptr<Data> elem`, and the `shared_ptr<Data> value` that's about to be assigned.

Something like:

```cpp
shared_ptr<Data> elem = visit(elem_node)
shared_ptr<Data> value = visit(value_node)
*elem = *value;
```

> Sorry, I forgot to say that visit() returns a value, not a reference, that's why I didn't just let elem=value;

It turns out the only thing that has been changed is the data member from the `Data` class.

But what I want is to let the `shared_ptr` "repoint" to a new object. Is it possible?

I've tried `dynamic_pointer_cast`, if the origin element and the new value are of the same type, everything is fine. But as I pointed out, I allow different types of elements in one list, so this can only be my last straw.

I've written a demo code based on Remy Lebeau's answer(thanks):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    virtual ~Data() = default;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

struct Integer : Data
{
    int value;
    Integer(int val) : value(val) {}
    void print() override { cout << "integer(" << value << ")" << endl; }
};

struct String : Data
{
    string value;
    String(string val) : value(val) {}
    void print() override { cout << "string(\"" << value << "\")" << endl; }
};

struct RuntimeResult
{
    RuntimeResult success(const shared_ptr<Data> &value)
    {
        this->value = value;
        return (*this);
    }

    shared_ptr<Data> registry(const RuntimeResult &res)
    {
        // this is for handling error
        // but this simplify version simply return value;
        return res.value;
    }

    shared_ptr<Data> value;
};

int main()
{
    // simulate a List variable
    vector<shared_ptr<Data>> list;
    list.push_back(make_shared<Integer>(123456));
    list.push_back(make_shared<String>("hello"));

    RuntimeResult res;

    // inside registry, it should be something like visit_IndexNode(elem_node)
    // to interprete a node on AST Tree
    // but the return is simply like what have shown below
    shared_ptr<Data> elem = res.registry(RuntimeResult().success(list.at(0)));
    // Using Visual Studio 2019's debugging mode
    // we can see that elem's ptr == list[0]'s ptr
    // in other word, they are pointing to the same thing(123456)

    shared_ptr<Data> value = res.registry(RuntimeResult().success(make_shared<String>("test")));

    elem = value;
    elem->print(); // "test"

    list[0]->print(); // still 123456

    return 0;
}
```

this shows exactly my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what I want is to let the `shared_ptr` "repoint" to a new object. Is it possible?

Yes. Simply assign one `shared_ptr<Data>` to another, no casting needed:

```
shared_ptr<Data> &elem = ...;
shared_ptr<Data> value = ...;
elem = value;
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/HZwdR9)

Comment: The reason you can do that is by returning a reference. I've tried that but it kept crashing at increment use count, with that 0xCCCCCCCC memory access error, so my return value is just a shared_ptr without &

Comment: I'll see if I can do that. But you can just go see my repo if that's ok https://github.com/Morphlng/Basic. The part that you want to see is under src/Interpreter. Where the problem occur is in function visit_MutateNode, and the code that suppose to return shared_ptr elem, is right below it, visit_IndexNode.

Comment: @Morphlng your example doesn't do what you are asking for, since it is not modifying the contents of the list at all. My example does. Also, your example does not demonstrate the memory access error, either. Please update your question with a [mcve] that does,dont ask people to download code from an external site. But I can tell you that the code you pointed out is very inefficient and needs some serious rewriting. You are making a lot of unnecessary object copies, and your typed handling is just plain ugly. There are much better design choices (polymorphism, etc)

Comment: yes, it's my first time using these polymorphism things, I'll tried to better these code after I achieved most functions.

Answer (score 0):

As Remy pointed out, my origin problem was due to a bad design. However, I've managed to get around it by using `shared_ptr<unique_ptr<Base>>`.

The idea was to somehow change all reference of the `shared_ptr` to "re-point" to a new derived object. Following that idea, I've found a Q&A [Replace all references to a object in a shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185842/replace-all-references-to-a-object-in-a-shared-ptrt)

By adding the second layer of indirection, I can do things like:

```cpp
class Data;

class Integer:public Data;

class String:public Data;

shared_ptr<unique_ptr<Data>> origin_value = make_shared<unique_ptr<Data>>(make_unique<Integer>(123));

auto copy = origin_value;

shared_ptr<unique_ptr<Data>> new_value = make_shared<unique_ptr<Data>>(make_unique<String>("hello"));

(*copy).reset((*new_value).release());
```

This will change both `origin_value` and `copy` to `new_value`.